# Iterating over scraped lists in SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to scrape parts of JIRA information into lists. This works correctly. But after I try to add this information into my SQLalchemy it won't add or commit anything. Where does it come from? While debugging I see the correct values in the variables fields.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Date, Boolean, PrimaryKeyConstraint, UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from Dataextractie import testplanImport, testExecutionImport, projectversionImport
from jira_ext import JiraExt
import json
from datetime import datetime
#from Databasemodel import Requirements, TestSet, Test, ProjectVersion, TestPlan, Testexecutie, TestRun

jiraServer = JiraExt(snip)
Base = declarative_base()


#class Requirements(Base):
#    __tablename__ = "requirements"
#
#    ReqID = Column('reqid', Integer, primary_key=True)
#    Tags = Column('tags', String)
#    Desc = Column('desc', String)




#class TestSet(Base):
#    __tablename__ = "testset"

#    TestSetID = Column('testsetid', Integer, primary_key=True)
#    TestSetName = Column('testsetname', String)
#    TestSetDesc = Column('testsetdesc', String)
#    Testid = Column('testid', String, ForeignKey('test.testid'))


class ProjectVersion(Base):
    __tablename__ = "projectversion"
    #__table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint('productrelease.releaseid', 'productrelease.productid'),)

    Projectid = Column('projectid', String, primary_key=True)
    Desc = Column('desc', String)
    Tags = Column('tags', String)

            #ForeignKeyConstraint(['productid'], ['products.productid'])

class TestPlan(Base):
    __tablename__ = "testplan"
    #__table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint('testplan.runid', 'testplan.reqid'),)

    PlanID = Column('planid', String, primary_key=True)
    ProjectID = Column('projectid', String, ForeignKey('projectversion.projectid'))
    Naam = Column('naam', String)
        #ForeignKeyConstraint(['reqid', 'runid'], ['requirements.reqid', 'testrun.runid'])


class Testexecutie(Base):
    __tablename__ = "testexecutie"
    #__table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint('testexecutie.runid', 'testexecutie.testcadeid'),)

    Planid = Column('planid', String, ForeignKey("testplan.planid"), primary_key=True)
    Testdesc = Column('testdesc', String)
    ExecutieID = Column('executieid', String, primary_key=True)
    Status = Column('status', String)
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('executieid'),)

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = "test"
    #__table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint('testcase.testcaseid'),)

    TestID = Column('testid', String, primary_key=True)
    Casename = Column('casename', String)
    Executieid = Column('ExecutieID', String, ForeignKey('testexecutie.executieid'), primary_key=True)
    Result = Column('result', String)

#class TestRun(Base):
#    __tablename__ = "testrun"
#    #__table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint('runid', 'releaseid'),)
#
#    RunID = Column('runid', String, primary_key=True)
#    ExecutieID = Column('executieid', String, ForeignKey('testexecutie.executieid'))
#    TestID = Column('testid', String, ForeignKey('test.testid'))
#    Tags = Column('tags', String)
#    Tsttimestart = Column('testtimestart', Date, nullable=False)
#    Tsttimeend = Column('testtimeend', Date, nullable=False)
#    Testresult = Column('testresult', String, nullable=False)
#    Testoutput = Column('testoutput', String)

        #ForeignKeyConstraint(['runid', 'releaseid'], ['testexecutie.runid', 'productrelease.releaseid'])



engine = create_engine('snip', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

############################################## Session Open, Klaar voor invoer

Dataextraction = testExecutionImport("10100")
counter = 0
for identifier in Dataextraction[5]:
    projectversion = ProjectVersion()
    testplan = TestPlan()
    projectversion.Projectid = "10100"
    testplan.ProjectID = "10100"
    testplan.PlanID = identifier
    #testplan.Naam = identifier[0]["summary"]

    session.add(projectversion, testplan)
    counter +=1
    session.commit

for identifier in Dataextraction[6]:
    counter = 0
    testexecutie = Testexecutie()
    testexecutie.ExecutieID = identifier
    testexecutie.Planid = Dataextraction[5][counter]
    session.add(testexecutie)
    counter +=1
    session.commit  

for identifier in Dataextraction[4]:
    counter = 0
    test = Test()
    test.TestID = identifier
    test.Executieid = Dataextraction[2][counter]
    test.Result = Dataextraction[3][counter]
    session.add(test)
    counter +=1
    session.commit





session.close()
```

In case it's my scraper this is the code:

```
from jira_ext import JiraExt
import json
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Date, Boolean, PrimaryKeyConstraint, UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from collections import namedtuple

jiraServer = JiraExt(url="Snip")





def testExecutionImport(projectplan):
    testplanid = jiraServer.projectGetTestPlans(projectplan)
    listtestplanid = []
    listtestid = []
    liststatus = []
    listexecutieid = []
    listindvexecutieid = []
    listtestplannaam = []
    listprojectid = []
    for issue in testplanid["issues"]:
        print(issue["key"])

        listtestplannaam.append(issue["fields"])
        listprojectid.append(projectplan)
        #listexecutieid.append(issue["id"])
        executionsintestplan = jiraServer.testPlanGetAllTestExecutions(issue["key"])
        for key in executionsintestplan:
        #for i in range(executionsintestplan):
            importapi = jiraServer.testExecutionGetTests(key["key"])
            currentexecutieid = key["key"]
            listindvexecutieid = key["key"]
            listtestplanid.append(issue["key"])
            for key in importapi:
                #testid = jiraServer.testExecutionGetTests(executionsintestplan)
                #executieid = jiraServer.testExecutionGetTests(executionsintestplan)
                #status = jiraServer.testExecutionGetTests(executionsintestplan)

                listtestid.append(key["key"])
                listexecutieid.append(currentexecutieid)
                liststatus.append(key["status"])
        #values["projectplanid"]=projectplan
        # values["testid"] = testid
        # values["executieid"] = executieid
        # values["status"] = status
        # values["planid"] = testplanid

    return listtestplannaam, listprojectid, listexecutieid, liststatus, listtestid, listtestplanid, listindvexecutieid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually calling `session.commit` - you're just referencing the method:

```
session.commit
```

.. should be:

```
session.commit()
```